# Show custom field on Submissions page in CP

Tags: plugin-amforms

In A&M Forms, I'd like to show a custom field on the Submissions page in the control panel to make it easier to quickly reference the submissions.

Is this possible?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE3dz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click on the wheel icon below `Volunteer` and check if the field is available there, if not you can modify the `ElementType` and change it's `defineAvailableTableAttributes` function in order to add the field/fields you want.

I don't know how this plugin was build but I made several custom `ElementTypes` in Craft 2 with or without a custom layout and it works every time the same.

[Here](https://craftcms.com/classreference/elementtypes/EntryElementType#defineAvailableTableAttributes-detail) is the function for Craft entries. You can then set these values in the [getTableAttributeHtml](https://craftcms.com/classreference/elementtypes/EntryElementType#getTableAttributeHtml-detail) function